# retro-compatibility of HTML5 doctype?

Tags: xml, html, magento, doctype, w3c

My magento project include both strict

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and transitional

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

doctype templates.

In an effort to harmonize this, I would be tempted to change it all to HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Is it a good idea and what could be the possible consequence of it?

Will my `a target` attributes still work for example?:

```
   <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Do you only care if the attribute will still *work*, or do you want to know if it’s *allowed* to use in HTML5?

Comment: @unor i wanna know if everything contained in my templates will be retrocompatible if i switch to html5 doctype or if some of my templates fonctionnality might not work

Comment: Anything not part of the html5 spec will force browsers into their quirks mode and will (probably) work. However if you are switching to html5 you should be going through your templates and updating them

Answer (score 0):

The only effect the doctype string (or lack thereof) has on the browsers is selecting between the Quirks, Standards, or Almost Standards modes. The other details provided in the doctype string are effectively ignored.

Assuming the doctypes are at the very start of the document served as `text/html`:

**1) Changing the first (...Strict...) doctype to the HTML5 doctype should have no effect on the browsers you're likely to care about.**

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` string was specifically chosen as the simplest string that triggered the *Standards mode* in the browsers, just as your Strict doctype does. (See [Ian Hickson's comment on this](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/3dqfqt/why_is_the_html5_doctype_so_simple/ct7xwbv/).)

**2) Changing the second (...Transitional...) doctype to the HTML5 doctype will switch the modern browsers from the ["Almost Standards" mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko's_Almost_Standards_Mode) to "Standards" mode when rendering the page.**

The change from Almost Standards to Standards ("No-quirks") mode affects layout in one well-defined (though hard to explain succintly) case. It will definitely affect you if your code is using the web development techniques from early 2000s and lay out the page using <table>s. It does not affect `<a href="" target=`. You will have to test this change to know if it affects you.

---

Source: *Appendix: Handling of Some Doctypes in text/html* here: https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/